# set document.getElementById().style = .cssclass in ASPX page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Code first:

```
<style type="text/css">
.label1 {
font-weight: bold;
color: #006699;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(k) {
document.getElementById(k).style = label1; <--this does not work
    }
</script>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to set the style of the element *(which is a label defined in code-behind file (Default.aspx.cs))* using a .CSSclass?

Understand that I can apply `.style.color` to set color or etc, but would like to see if above is possible first.

The function test(k) is called from code-behind.  Tested to be working.

Answer (score 1):

> `document.getElementById(k).style = label1; <--this does not work`

There's no reason it would, you don't have a JavaScript variable called `label1`, and you don't apply classes by assigning to `.style` (though I can see why you'd think of doing it).

Your CSS defines a class. To give the element that class, on [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
document.getElementById(k).classList.add("label1");
```

For older browsers like IE9 and earlier, use `className`, which is a space-separated list of classes (like the HTML `class` attribute):

```
document.getElementById(k).className += " label1";
```

---

> The function test(k) is called from code-behind.

Just make sure `k` is the *client-side* ID of the element. (I think the property for the client-side ID on the server control is creatively named [`ClientID`](http://v), but ASP.Net isn't my thing, apologies if that's the wrong tech.)

Comment: @T.JCrowder Works like a charm and yes, label1 just by itself would be nothing but a variable.  Also noted on the control naming. 
The ".classlist / .classname" is what is missing I think.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: No worries, glad that helped!